# status bar position is not proper when wkWebview plugin is added in iOS phonegap application

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing iOs application using phonegap.

phonegap version : 3.5.0

xcode version : 6.1.1

I have added the "org.apache.cordova.statusbar" plugin for the status bar. My application is working fine on iOs 7 & iOs 8. But for better performance in iOs 8, I have added the "com.telerik.plugins.wkwebview" plugin. After adding this plugin, header part of application is destroy and looking that it is inside status bar. I have also attached image with this question. I have added the following property in my_project-info.plist file:

```
Status bar is initially hidden : NO
View controller-based status bar appearance : YES
```

[image: header and status bar position]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the "- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated" method from MainViewController.m file and replace the method with following code.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // View defaults to full size.  If you want to customize the view's size, or its subviews (e.g. webView),
    // you can do so here.
    //Lower screen 20px on iOS 7 and iOS 8

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7){
        CGRect viewBounds = [self.webView bounds];
        viewBounds.origin.y = 20;
        viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 20;
        self.webView.frame = viewBounds;
    }
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

This solution has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue using following steps

1) Go to your project explorer, click on class folder there is file **"MainViewController.m"**, add code

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

2) Go to your project explorer, click on **Resources** folder there is file like "Your_project_name-Info.plist" add here as key **View controller-based status bar appearance** and value **YES**.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. But in your solution, status bar is hidden, But I want that status bar should be on the proper position and status bar should not be hidden.